Combining Loggers and Appenders from Multiple Properties Files in Log4j2?
I have a simple web application (sample.war) deployed on Tomcat, which uses a log4j2.properties file for logging configuration by default. Now, I need to create a logger configuration from a different properties file (mylog.properties) without losing the existing loggers and appenders defined in the original log4j2.properties.
I attempted to configure the logger using the following code:
public void configure(Properties props) {
    File mylogpropsFile = new File("mylog.properties");
    props.store(new FileOutputStream(mylogpropsFile), "");
    ConfigurationSource fromUri = ConfigurationSource.fromUri(mylogpropsFile.toURI());
    loggerContext = Configurator.initialize(null, fromUri);
    loggerContext.setConfigLocation(mylogpropsFile.toURI());
}

While this approach successfully initializes the loggerContext with the properties from mylog.properties, it overrides the existing loggers and appenders because the setConfigLocation method performs a reconfiguration.
What I need is a way to ensure that both the loggers and appenders from log4j2.properties and mylog.properties coexist within the same loggerContext object. Is there a way to achieve this in Log4j2?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
"I'd appreciate it if you could avoid questions about why I'm using different properties files instead of a single one.

The log4j2.configurationFile Log4j configuration property accepts a comma-separated list of URIs, so you can simply set it to classpath:log4j2.properties,classpath:mylog.properties.
If you really need to pass the values from code, you can use the Configurator.initialize overload that takes a List<URI> as parameter.
Multiple configuration files will create a CompositeConfiguration. See CompositeConfiguration for the details of the default merging mechanism.
